# Does Ant Support File-based Dependencies?

Tags: java, ant

I would like to make an ant dependency where the target file depends on a source file. How do you describe this in ant?

For example, convert this Make target to ant

```
data.txt: header1.txt body.txt footer.txt
      cat header1.txt body.txt footer.txt > data.txt
```

Comment: providing alittle more information might help you come to a solution, so are you saying if file A changed then execute task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My simple solution right now is to manually add a test for the source/dest file age in my shell script called from exec task in ant.

Comment: I'm 10 years late to the party, but like you were 10 years ago, i'm completely baffled to see that ant cannot do this out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do something like this, but it's starting to sound like scripting.  Ant isn't a scripting language.  If you have a lot of "if/then/else" logic in mind you're probably doing it wrong.

Please describe "other data".  Are we talking about copying files?  Is this a devl/test/prod environment issue?  In that case, you can certainly pass in a parameter specifying environment name and using conditional tests to decide which set to copy.  Read [this](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html) to see how.

Comment: Isn't the point of ant to decide how to build a project? Does that mean it has to do a full build every time?

Comment: Ant is smart enough to only compile the code that's been touched.  Why is doing a full build every time a problem?  The only issue that I can think of is long-running unit tests.  If that's the case, make those separate.

Comment: It's not the code base I'm concerned about. My build system needs to deploy other data to my system for my application. This is something Make can handle effortlessly. If I can't do a one-step build with Ant, then what are the other options? Is it common to wrap ant inside of Make?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just wanting to bring files in one directory up-to-date with respect to your source tree,
you might use the [`sync`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sync.html) task.  Here's a basic example from the docs:

```
<sync todir="site">
  <fileset dir="generated-site"/>
</sync>
```

> overwrites all files in *site* with
>   newer files from *generated-site*,
>   deletes files from *site* that are not
>   present in *generated-site.*

If you need to determine which resources need update,
in order to carry out a more complex operation than a sync,
you might use the [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) [`outofdate`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/outofdate.html) task.  For example

```
<outofdate property="compile.needed" outputsourcespath="sources.for.recompile">
    <sourcefiles>
        <fileset dir="${src}" includes="*.c"/>
    </sourcefiles>
    <mapper type="glob" dir="${src}" from="*.c" to="${obj}/*.o"/>
</outofdate>
```

will set `compile.needed` to true if any object files are out-of-date compared to source,
and also set the path `sources.for.recompile` with a list of just the sources that need recompile -
you can then compile for just those sources.

(The assumption here is that a single file in the build output area is directly related to one source.)

Comment: thanks, but I'm still baffled how a core design of Make is regarded as a add-on to ant?